# Error resolving RC2 JwtBearerToken libraries

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm attempting to create bearer tokens in an AspNetCore application.

I'm getting the following error:  The dependency Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens >= 5.0.0-rc2-305061149 could not be resolved

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server": "0.1.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"System.IdentityModel.Tokens": "5.0.0-rc2-305061149",
"System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.0.0-rc2-305061149"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" has version "5.0.0-rc2-305061149", the last version for "System.IdentityModel.Tokens" is "5.0.0-rc1-211161024".